# Employee(s) Payroll Gross Pay Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

My assignment is to create a code that will calculate an employee(s) gross pay with a constraint of the hourly pay cannot be lower than $8.  I am unsure why my code will not run, no errors show when being compiled.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);

    int numEmployees = key.nextInt();
    int employeeName[] = new int[numEmployees];
    int hoursWorked[] = new int[numEmployees];
    int hourlyWage[] = new int[numEmployees];
    int grossWages[] = new int[numEmployees];

    System.out.println("Enter the number of employess whose gross wages"
            + " you wish to calculate:");
    //user enter employee name

    for(int i = 1; i < employeeName.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter name of employee " + i+ ":");
        employeeName[i]= key.nextInt();
        i++;
    }

    //user enters number of hours
    //System.out.println("How many hours did" + employeeName[i] + " work this week?");

    for(int i = 0; i< numEmployees; i++)
    {
        System.out.print("How many hours did" + employeeName[i] + " work this week?");
        hoursWorked[i] = key.nextInt();

        //get the hourly pay rate
        System.out.print("What is" + employeeName[i] + " hourly wage?");
        //hourlyWage = key.nextInt();

        grossWages[i] = hoursWorked[i] * hourlyWage[i];
    }
    //displays wages
    System.out.println("The hours and pay rates you entered are:");

    for(int i = 0; i < numEmployees; i++)
    {
        //hourlyWage = key.nextInt();
        System.out.printf("The total wages for Employee #%d is $%.2f\n", employeeName[i], hourlyWage);
    }

    //System.out.print("");
    //System.out.print("Name     Hours Worked     Hourly Pay Rate     Gross Wages Earned");
    //System.out.println(employeeName + "     " + hoursWorked + "     " + hourlyWage + "     " + grossWages);
```

}
}

Comment: Java is to Javascript as Pain is to Painting, or Ham is to Hampster. They are completely different. It is highly recommended that aspiring coders try to learn the name of the language they're attempting to write code in. When you post a question, please tag it appropriately.

Comment: That's funny @CertainPerformance, especially "Pain is to Painting", I'm going to steal, I mean use that - it's especially funny because the javascript tag states *not to be confused with java*

Answer (score 0):

1) Prompt before accepting input

```
System.out.println("Enter the number of employess whose gross wages"
        + " you wish to calculate:");
```

then

```
int numEmployees = key.nextInt();
```

2) Start loop at zero

```
for(int i = 1; i < employeeName.length; i++)
```

3) uncomment

```
//hourlyWage = key.nextInt();
```

**edit**

why would an employee name be an `int` ?

Answer (score 0):

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);

int numEmployees = key.nextInt();
int employeeName[] = new int[numEmployees];
int hoursWorked[] = new int[numEmployees];
int hourlyWage[] = new int[numEmployees];
int grossWages[] = new int[numEmployees];

System.out.println("Enter the number of employess whose gross wages"
        + " you wish to calculate:");
//user enter employee name

for(int i = 1; i < employeeName.length; i++)
{
    System.out.println("Enter name of employee " + i+ ":");
    employeeName[i]= key.nextInt();
    i++;
}

//user enters number of hours
//System.out.println("How many hours did" + employeeName[i] + " work this week?");

for(int i = 0; i< numEmployees; i++)
{
    System.out.print("How many hours did" + employeeName[i] + " work this week?");
    hoursWorked[i] = key.nextInt();

    //get the hourly pay rate
    System.out.print("What is" + employeeName[i] + " hourly wage?");
    hourlyWage[i] = key.nextInt();

    grossWages[i] = hoursWorked[i] * hourlyWage[i];
}
//displays wages
System.out.println("The hours and pay rates you entered are:");

for(int i = 0; i < numEmployees; i++)
{
    //hourlyWage = key.nextInt();
    System.out.printf("The total wages for Employee #%d is $%.2f\n", employeeName[i], hourlyWage[i]);
}

//System.out.print("");
//System.out.print("Name     Hours Worked     Hourly Pay Rate     Gross Wages Earned");
//System.out.println(employeeName + "     " + hoursWorked + "     " + hourlyWage + "     " + grossWages);
```

} }

Comment: Please do not post code only answers, please explain what you have done.